# Why the mesh cannot punch a hole all over

Tags: modeling, modifiers

With the simple mesh. I cannot punch hole. One side its in the middle part and other side its top part.

[image]

[image]

Face orientation, Scale rotation looks good, Why its not creating hole all over the mesh. Any suggestion. Thanks

**If there is any other way or addon can make simple grid hole plz mention.**

Comment: Hello, could you put a little more effort into your question ? As it is, it is near to impossible to answer your question. You expect us to download your file and figure it out ourselves but your post should contain all the necessary information to solve the problem. Cheers

Comment: If you change the Boolean to 'intersection', you see a lot of lines which correspond to the dashed ones in your screenshot.

Comment: I would suggest cleanly modelling one hole, use the array mod. to replicate it and then cut the rims.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boolean often doesn't work because of overlapping vertices, edges or faces, so move your boolean object (Cylinder.005) up a bit and it works:

[image]